# How do I use implicit function theorem to get second derivative of a function?

Tags: implicit-function-theorem

Consider

$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$

acc. to implicit function theorem,

$ y' =  \frac{-x}{y}$

Now how would I find y'' by using implicit theorem again?

and what would be my multivariable function? , would it be $F(x,y,y') = y y' +x $

EDit: I mean using implicit function theorem again... I don't want direct derivative!!

Comment: I meant using implicit function theorem!! not direct differentiation

Comment: If I understood correctly, acc. to implicit funct theorem$, y' = \frac{ -\frac{dF}{dx} } { \frac{dF}{dy}}$

Comment: edit:I'm asking if we can use implcit function theorem again on that to get y'' , i.e find y'' using partial derivatives

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$y y^\prime +x = 0.$$ Differentiate this relation according to $x$, you get

$$\left(y^\prime\right)^2 + y y^{\prime \prime} + 1 =0.$$

Replace $y' =  \frac{-x}{y}$ in the equation above and you get:

$$y^{\prime \prime} = - \frac{1}{y} - \frac{x^2}{y^3}$$

Comment: this is not what I wanted

Comment: Can you tell what you wanted? $y y^\prime + x=0$ is the implicit relation linking $y, y^\prime, x$. It is from the implicit relation $x^2 + y^2 =r^2$ that you got $y' =  \frac{-x}{y}$.

Comment: I'm asking if we can use implcit function theorem again on that to get y'' , i.e find y'' using partial derivatives

Comment: That is exactly what I did with $F(x,y,y^\prime) = y y^\prime +x$.